# Trigger a custom jquery event

Tags: jquery, events, triggers

I'm creating some form elements dynamically and I need to trigger an event for each element.

Say I have something like this:

```
$("#select_123").val("easy").change().trigger("createRow");


$("#container").bind("createRow",function() {
   //doStuff
}
```

How do I chain .trigger to run the "createRow" event??  Even better, how can I use .delegate instead of .bind?

Comment: I'm not following your question. If you hook the event *before* triggering it (the above hooks it *after*), you'll receive the event.

Comment: Side note: `.bind` and `.delegate` are thoroughly outdated. The modern method to use is [`on`](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: oh wow, re-ordered and it worked. ok cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fires the event before you've hooked up a handler for it. If you reverse the order, it'll work.

It'll also work with event delegation, because jQuery's custom events bubble by default. So you just trigger the event on the child and watch for it on the parent.

Example:

```js
$(".child").on("click", function() {
  // Fire the custom event on the child element
  $(this).trigger("custom-event");
});

// Watch for custom events using delegation
$("#parent").on("custom-event", ".child", function(e) {
  console.log("Got event: " + e.type);
});
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">Click me</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```